# Conversation with an Atheist

Tags: atheists, atheism

Salam Aliakoum

Newly I got an atheist friend and she want to get answers for her concerns:

Where is your God when Muslim women get r***d, or forced to merry violent men, get killed by stones and whip in public???
Omosexual men get biten and killed because your God says Omosexuality is wrong. Who are you to judge them? Who are you to hurt them in the name of your God??
More over: when children back passage is r***d by old men... Where is your God??

She said: Don't waste my time with boring stupid religious answers which includes :
1)God plans for a better life afterwords.
2)god is testing us in this life.
3)is was not God it was the devil.
4)I have got an sheikh who just said 1 and only simple question: WHERE IS YOUR GOD WHEN MUSLIM WOMEN AND CHILDREN GET R***D BY MUSLIM MEN.
WHERE IS THEIR GOD???

I’m really stucked with her because she seems already won’t to believe in this points above, so what the best and fully answer would to share with her?

Appreciate your answer
Thanks in advance
Kind Regards

Answer (score 2):

She doesn't want you to waste her time with answers that she already decided she doesn't like. That is not the attitude of someone who wants answers, that is the attitude of someone who wants to disbelieve in a God that doesn't meet her own made-up criteria.

In this case, she somehow wants Allah to be a God who magically protects people from everything that might hurt them, one who doesn't have the supreme authority to judge right from wrong, one who personally intervenes whenever things are difficult. This is not what Allah does, nor is it anything that Allah has promised.

There's only two ways this can go: either you're wasting her time teaching her about a god that she already decided to reject, or you'll be wasting your own time convincing her to believe in a god who doesn't exist. Either way, it's pointless.